# VB.NET Installed Application suddenly "not installed"

Tags: vb.net

I have written many VB.NET apps over the years and installed them across our company (all in-house) suddenly yesterday a lot of my applications all asked the users to "Install" the program however looking at the Installed Programs it was still listed and the shortcut was still on the desktop however not with the program icon but the one when a program hasn't been removed correctly. I thought it was a blimp and installed and put all of the settings back in, came in this morning and the same thing has happened again.

I've been writing/installing these program for 15+ years and nothing like this has happened before.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as this is so weird I don't know where to start,  as so far it isn't all of my programs and it isn't happening to every user who users the same program and it has also affected satellite sites away from our main Head Office. Once installed and setup up the program continues to work as expected. To my knowledge no new AV has been installed and they are all running on Win10.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: We're going to need all the specific details of how the application was deployed. Also, please review your tags as this doesn't really seem related to VB.NET specifically at all.

Comment: Plus all the info about your network/server infrastructure, i.e. have your sysadmin guys perhaps done something with user profiles / install locations?

Comment: Had the same thing recently.  Windows defender had quarantined the exe files.

Comment: Did this happen after installing KB5029649? Someone else here asked about [ClickOnce thinks there's an update available after Windows Update KB5029649, even when there's none](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76882559/1115360).

Comment: Perhaps the network team implemented a white list of allowed software on company computers, forgetting to consult teams creating in-house software? That would be normal, unfortunately.