# ClickOnce thinks there's an update available after Windows Update KB5029649, even when there's none

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, windows-update

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm experiencing an unusual issue with our ClickOnce deployed VB.NET applications. Despite not having published any recent updates, some of our users are prompted to update the application. When they proceed, it behaves as if it's a fresh installation, wiping out all previous user configurations. Additionally, upon reopening the app, the update prompt returns.

The peculiarity seems to have started after the Windows update KB5029649. However, this issue isn't consistent across all machines with this update, making it even more puzzling.

Here's what I've observed and tried so far:

- Cleaning the ClickOnce cache via rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache provides a temporary fix, but the problem re-emerges after a few days for some users.
- We've checked manifest files and ensured no accidental changes or commits are causing this.
- Some machines with the exact same Windows update (KB5029649) do not face this issue at all, suggesting other potential variables at play.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this or how to further diagnose the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation, it seems I've found the root cause of the issue. I'm sharing this in case there's anyone else still struggling with this.

It appears the issue was due to a problem with the Windows update KB5028244.

According to [their official update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22H2#apps-deployed-via-clickonce-might-prompt-for-installation-when-opened), a temporary solution is to uninstall and then reinstall the application. However, they will address the issue via a Known Issue Rollback (KIR).

Comment: thanks so much for this information. I was really shocked to receive so many support cases across many products without knowing what I did wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The update `KB5028244` is the problem (you might have noticed the problem after a Windows Update.)
A fix could be tu uninstall the update : `cmd` > `wusa /uninstall /kb:5028244`.

You can also disable the Scheduled Task which is causing the problem :
[image]

Or download the KIR ([what is it ?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/known-issue-rollback-helping-you-keep-windows-devices-protected/ba-p/2176831#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20publishes%20a%20specific%20Group%20Policy%20on%20the%20Download%20Center%20that%20can%20be%20used%20to%20configure%20and%20apply%20a%20rollback%20policy)) if you are a sys admin [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22h2#apps-deployed-via-clickonce-might-prompt-for-installation-when-opened:%7E:text=Windows%2010%2020H2%2C%2021H1%2C%2021H2%20and%2022H2%20KB5028244%20230627_173555%20Known%20Issue%20Rollback) :

[image]

Here's some documentations :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-22h2#apps-deployed-via-clickonce-might-prompt-for-installation-when-opened
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1343633/problem-with-multiple-clickonce-applications-needi
- https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-windows-10-kb5028244-app-installs-via-clickonce-incorrectly-nagging-users/

Warning : don't mix KB502**8**244 (which is causing the problem) and KB5029244

Answer (score 1):

[KB5029331](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/august-22-2023-kb5029331-os-build-19045-3393-preview-9f6c1dbd-0ee6-469b-af24-f9d0bf35ca18)  "August 22, 2023—KB5029331 (OS Build 19045.3393) Preview" says it includes a fix for this problem:

> This update addresses a known issue that affects ClickOnce. Apps that you used ClickOnce to deploy might begin to prompt for installation. This occurs even when the ClickOnce apps are already installed and marked as “trusted”.